# How to share the scrollbar between container and gridview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a column and inside it a page title then Griview.count to display a grid of items.

The gridview scrolls fine downward but the title stays always on top so is not scrollable in the default implementation. I changed the `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` for the gridview and then the grid itself does not scroll.

Afterward I wrapped the container in `SingleChildScrollView` and ended up with a partially buggy working solution.

The simplified code so far is:

```
class ExampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleViewState createState() => _ExampleViewState();
}

class _ExampleViewState extends State<ExampleView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBody(['afsfdfdss', 'dffdfd', 'item3', 'item4 just example']);
  }

  Widget _buildBody(List<String> data) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Some title'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(data.length,
                        (index) => _buildItem(index, data[index])),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(int index, String item) {
    return Text(item);
  }
}
```

Note:
I used SingleChildScrollView to wrap the container and because it needs to know the height I used mediaquery.

This works partially. I can scroll down the title is scrolling but cannot go until the end of the Gridview!!! so I see the items cropper and not all of them.

If I increase the height for instance:

```
height: MediaQuery .of(context).size.height + 1000,
```

then this works fine I can scroll down until the bottom of gridview and even further so have a lot of white space.

What is the proper fix to:
Have only scrollbar for the entire _buildBody Widget, so when I scroll down also the title scrolls down and I can go until the bottom of the gridview.
With my current approach the problem is that don't know the height beforehand so singlechildscrollbar is not working well

I uploaded some illustrative videos as well to explain easier.
The default behaviour which of course is not a bug and works as intended, the title does not scroll.
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uRBUO49XM6E
I want to be able to scroll also the title when scroll down the grid items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you don't need the heigh, just remove `Flexible` and Container's `height` and add `shrinkWrap: true` to `GridView`, like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Some title'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(data.length,
                        (index) => _buildItem(index, data[index])),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried that but get empty white screen after removing the containers height. Wait have to remove flexible as well forgot that. Update: Worked great!!! I have to research read what shrinkWrap does but solved the issue

Comment: Yes it worked!!! Thanks a lot for such an elegant solution with 2 line changes. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes as stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept answer in first 6 min. Worked great and am reading the details of the solutions why it worked the shrinkWrap

Comment: glad to help. more about [shrinkWrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html)